# Правильное отображение цвета mix-blend-mode

Tags: css, scss

Ситуация следующая: есть плавающий блок с `position: fixed` (навигационное меню). К нему применяется `mix-blend-mode: difference`, этот блок при прокручивании наезжает на блок с `background: black` и все работает как нужно (черный текст на белом фоне и белый текст на черном фоне). Однако при наведении мыши (`:hover` эффект), цвет должен быть  `#dc145c`, но из-за `mix-blend-mode: difference` он зеленый. `isolation: isolate` не помогает, есть ли другое решение?
[Примерное демо](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/cranky-night-m5pp58?file=%2Fsrc%2Fstyles.css%3A14%2C14)

```
$Black-color: #040404;
$Pin-color: #dc145c;
$White-color: #fff;


.logoContainer {
  top: 60px;
  position: fixed;
  margin-bottom: 29px;
}

.menu {
  top: 128px;
  position: fixed;
}

.navigate ul {
  background: inherit;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.chapter {
  background: inherit;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 300;

  .chapterLink {
    color: $White-color;
    text-decoration: none;

    &:hover {
      color: $Pin-color;
    }
  }
}

.chapter:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Приведите работаюшую модель. для теста.

Comment: @BlackStar1991, добавил.
Не очень ровно, но проблема ясна

Comment: Я правильно понял, что при наведении текст всегда должен быть розового цвета ?

Comment: @BlackStar1991, да, именно так